# Asynchronous Oracle NoSQL client?

Tags: oracle-nosql, nosql

I have used Datastax [Cassandra driver](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.0/common/drivers/introduction/introArchOverview_c.html), which is based on [Netty](http://netty.io/) that allows for "true" asynchronous processing (which in turn uses Java NIO, not the threadpool idea that still uses one thread per connection under the hood).

Is there something similar in the Oracle NoSQL client?  The latest version ([3.2.5](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/nosqldb/downloads/index.html)) doesn't seem to support it, which is major reason we can't adopt it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

No, we currently don't have asynchronous java drivers. Although, this is something in our road-map.